# Disable keyboard layout switching for certain applications (or e.g. window classes) only

Tags: kde, keyboard-shortcuts

I have configured some key combination to switch keyboard layouts in KDE Plasma. But for some applications (or maybe window classes) from the list (e.g., remote desktop or virtual machines) I want this key just pass the keypress event to the application, **without switching keyboard layout** in KDE.

Is this possible? May be with some third-party application?

Comment: You could try changing the key comb in the application to a different key combo than the one that changes the keyboard layout.